Azure Ad SSO Authentication Fail and redirect back to login page then getting TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
I am facing issue with azure ad authentication in spring cloud, I have configured the things correctly but not sure why I am facing issue.
Problem: We are able to generate oauth code when we inspect the element in browser but it is unable to redirect to specified URL.
application.properties
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.client.provider=azuread
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.client.client-id=<client_ID>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.client.client-secret=<client_secret>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.client.client-authentication-method=client_secret_basic
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.client.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.client.redirect-uri={baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.client.scope=openid+email+profile
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.client.client-name=Login with Azure
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azuread.issuer-uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>/v2.0
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azuread.token-uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azuread.authorization-uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azuread.user-info-uri=https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo
azure.activedirectory.tenant-id=<tenant_ID>

SecurityConfig
@Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeExchange()
                    .pathMatchers("/signin/**")
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyExchange()
                    .authenticated()
                .and()
                    .oauth2Login() // to redirect to oauth2 login page.
        ;

        return http.build();
    }

Login Controller
@RequestMapping("/signin")
    private ResponseEntity<?> login(@Context ServerHttpRequest request, @AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User principal) throws JSONException {
        Map<String, String> userProfile = new HashMap<>();
        userProfile = authService.userLogin(principal);
        System.out.println("data from endpoint : "
                +principal.toString() );
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userProfile);
        //return Response.ok("Success").build();
    }


Trying to trigger login endpoint https://localhost:8080/signin and rendering to microsoft login page after filling credentials it is redirecting back to login page again and again. getting TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS ERROR. Expected to be redirect to signin controller after successful authentication for getting access_token.

I removed the @Bean annotation from the SecurityConfig class and updated the complete code as follows. I successfully signed in and obtained an access token.
Code :
SecurityConfig.java :
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/signin/**", "/login/oauth2/**").permitAll()
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and().oauth2Login();
        return http.build();
    }
}

LoginController.java :
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.annotation.RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.OidcUser;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.example.demo._6.service.AuthService;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthService authService;
    @RequestMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("azure") OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient,
                                   @AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser principal) {
        Map<String, String> response = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> userProfile = authService.userLogin(principal);
        response.putAll(userProfile);
        String accessToken = authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
        response.put("access_token", accessToken);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
}

AuthService.java :
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.OidcUser;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Service
public class AuthService {
    public Map<String, String> userLogin(OidcUser principal) {
        Map<String, String> userProfile = new HashMap<>();
        userProfile.put("name", principal.getFullName());
        userProfile.put("email", principal.getEmail());
        return userProfile;
    }
}

application.properties :
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-id=<client_ID>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-secret=<client_secret>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-authentication-method=client_secret_basic
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/azure
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.scope=openid,profile,email
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-name=Azure
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azure.issuer-uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>/v2.0
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azure.authorization-uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azure.token-uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azure.user-info-uri=https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo
azure.activedirectory.tenant-id=<tenant_ID>
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG

pom.xml :
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

I added the following URL to the Azure AD app's Authentication in the Web redirect URIs:
http://localhost:8080


Brower Output :
http://localhost:8080/signin

I entered the above URL in the browser, and it redirected me to the login page where I selected my account for sign-in:

After successfully signing in, I received my account details and access token:

Using the following URL, I navigated to the logout page and clicked the Log Out button to log out:
http://localhost:8080/logout


After logging out, I received the following:

Spring tool suite Console :



@Raj musham Have you tried the solution I provided?
